# Pod Install does not run which fails to launch Application

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos

Everytime I try `flutter run` on VS code to run my ios files, I seem to get an error with pod install. This is the Error:

```
Running pod install...                                             982ms
```

CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
[!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_insp
ector.rb:108:in `compute_targets'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_insp
ector.rb:40:in `compute_results'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1197:in
`block (3 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in
`each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in
`block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in
`each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in
`block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in
`section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in
`inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in
`analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in
resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in
`section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in
`resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install

I have tried all solutions and nothing seems to work. This error happens right after I try to connect my firebase to my code.

Comment: Are you indeed in the correct iOS folder before executing?

Comment: yeah the podfile is located in the ios folder which is alongside lib folder and android folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

**Step 1**: Remove Existing Pods Repo

If you want to start with a clean slate or you encounter issues with your current Pods repository, you can remove it:

```
pod repo remove master
```

**Step 2**: Initialize CocoaPods

Run the following command to initialize CocoaPods. This step ensures you have the necessary environment set up:

```
pod setup
```

**Step 3**: Install Dependencies

With CocoaPods set up, navigate to your Xcode project directory (where your .xcodeproj file is located) and run:

```
pod install
```

This command reads your Podfile, fetches the specified dependencies, and integrates them into your Xcode project.

**UPDATE**

***SKIP REMOVAL:*** The error message "repo master does not exist" suggests that there is no "master" repository configured in your CocoaPods installation. This can happen if you haven't previously added the master repository, or if you are using a more recent version of CocoaPods that no longer uses the "master" repository by default.

So simply, you can proceed with running `pod setup` and `pod install` as mentioned in the previous steps.

Comment: I got an error when trying to use pod repo remove master saying repo master does not exist

Comment: Try to skip that step. pod setup should do the trick

Comment: Error with step Number 3.                                                                               
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`. but RunnerTest code is already added to the podfile